# What is the difference between the two pieces of code that follow:

Tags: python

This first one uses asterisk by the other_pipes list:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en")
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]
nlp.disable_pipes(other_pipes)
```

However this other one doesn't:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en")
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]
nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes)
```

Even so they had similar outputs:

First:

```
[('tagger', <spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger at 0x2103ab55c88>),
 ('parser', <spacy.pipeline.pipes.DependencyParser at 0x2103a84cc48>)]
```

Second:

```
[('tagger', <spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger at 0x222faa86cc8>),
 ('parser', <spacy.pipeline.pipes.DependencyParser at 0x222f97bcca8>)]
```

Comment: Seems like that method just accepts both versions and does the same thing. https://spacy.io/api/language#disable_pipes

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now!